# UAC warning still occurs after program is uninstalled

Tags: windows-7, windows, uac

I have uninstalled a program but continue to get the UAC warning popup for that program every time I start my PC.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: What program is it? What is the name of the file in the UAC dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Off-topic:

[image: Grumpy Cat said Good]

On-topic:

Perhaps you have a virus or some sort of malware. Just try to kill the process of the application from Task Manager, or by using Process Explorer from [SysInternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx), then delete it. If that doesn't work, try running in Safe Mode, and then delete the application. Check if that application is not in Start Up. There are many things that might trigger that application to run on start up.

Comment: The application was The Missing Sync for Android.  I used it to sync my Nook Tablet to my iPhone.  However, I don't care about doing that any longer so have deleted the application.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll try and see if they work.

Comment: Make sure you also delete any services it left. I don't know if this application has any, but anyway. Stop the service, then start cmd as an administrator and run *sc delete <service_name>*